# How can we wrap results of SELECT statements in double quotes?

Tags: cassandra

How can we append double quotes or wrap results values with double quotes in cassandra select statement?

one option is to create user defined function, is it a good idea or is not not recommended and know to be performance challenge?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to natively do this with CQL. I also personally don't think it makes sense to do this server-side.

If you need to format the returned results, I think it is more ideal to do this client-side in your application. Cheers!